# STS ( Eclipse ) maven adding remote repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

Maven nube here.

How does one add a remote repository in STS.

pic 1) In preferences I added the  [apache maven snapshot repository archetype catalog](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/archetype-catalog.xml)

pic 2) But, dosent show up in the "Maven repository" window. Any help ?

pic 3) Is this a problem that I am missing the settings file ?

Am using the latest STS for Mac OS X 2.5.2SR1

[image: remote repository in preferences]

but dosent show up here

[image: but dosent show up here]

Is this a problem that I am missing the settings file ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the archetype-catalog.xml
2. Go to Maven > Archetypes and add a new local catalogs with the downloaded file
3. Select the new created catalog when creating new maven project, you will see archetypes there